# subtract datetime object from current time if datetime could either be offset-aware or naive

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am in a weird situation where I have a json file from which I am reading date time in `string` format. Then I parse it using `dateutil.parser.parse`.

The final `datetime` object is like this

```
2015-08-22 14:06:03-07:00
```

I need to subtract it from current time and get total number of days. Which I can easily do, but the problem is I don't always know the format of the above `datetime` from file (in some files it is offset aware while other times it isn't).

`datetime.datetime.now()` gives `2018-10-14 14:10:44.532932`

Is there any way to subtract any format of `datetime` from current `datetime`.

**Example,**

Format in file could return,

```
2015-08-22 14:06:03-07:00
```

or

```
2015-08-22 14:06:03.4421-07:00
```

or something else

Current date time returns `2018-10-14 14:19:10.510259` but parsed `datetime` returns `2013-06-20 13:39:30-07:00`. I know that both are `datetime` objects but when i subtract it I get

```
TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

I want to be able to subtract any of these format from current datetime.

Comment: If you're using `dateutil.parser.parse`, you'll end up with a `datetime` object no matter what the format is.  Why does the format matter after that point?

Comment: thank you for response. current date time is `2018-10-14 14:19:10.510259` but parsed datetime is `2013-06-20 13:39:30-07:00`
whhen i subtract it I get `TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the timezone when you get the current time.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
from pytz import timezone

et = timezone('US/Eastern')

x = parse('2015-08-22 14:06:03.4421-07:00')
y = datetime.now(tz=et)

print(y-x)
```